# Which CQI table should i choose for CQI value from telephony manager api

Tags: android, telephonymanager, lte, 4g, 5g

I am getting cqi value (Get channel quality indicator Reference: 3GPP TS 136.213 section 7.2.3.) from telephony manager, but now i am confused which exact table should i choose for 4g network and 5g network. In the docs they have mentioned about 3 tables each for 4g and 5g. I want to show the respective modulation for the cqi value from the telephony manager api.

https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/138200_138299/138214/16.02.00_60/ts_138214v160200p.pdf
https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/136200_136299/136213/14.02.00_60/ts_136213v140200p.pdf

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `getCqiTableIndex`/`getCsiCqiTableIndex` methods to get the CQI table index for LTE/5G.

For LTE the tables are defined in 3GPP 36.213 - section 7.2.3
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrengthLte#getCqiTableIndex()

For 5G the tables are defined in 3GPP 38.214 - section 5.2.2.1
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrengthNr#getCsiCqiTableIndex()